# How to build differently configured celery workers using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, celery

I am using docker-compose to build and run celery workers.

```
services:
    ...

    worker-a:
        command: celery -A tasks worker -l "DEBUG" --concurrency=1 -Q qname_a
        restart: always
        environment:
            WORKER_TYPE: a_setting
            ...
        depends_on:
            - ...

    worker-b:
        command: celery -A tasks worker -l "DEBUG" --concurrency=1 -Q qname_b
        restart: always
        environment:
            WORKER_TYPE: b_setting
            ...
        depends_on:
            - ...
```

How can I build 2 different worker images (worker-a and worker-b), which perform the same task (same code), but use different configurations (based on WORKER_TYPE) and listen to different queues?

Comment: I'd probably use a single image ("same code"), overriding `command:` and `environment:` ("configuration") exactly as you've done.  Are there problems you're running into with the approach you outline in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are aiming to avoid having to repeat an almost identical piece of code, YAML anchors are great for defining reusable blocks.

For example, in the below configuration all the configuration for `worker-a` can be used by any other service by calling `<<: *default`, and then overriding any value as needed:

```
version: '3'

services:
  worker-a: &default
    image: alpine
    command: env
    environment:
      WORKER_TYPE: a_setting
    # ... more definitions

  worker-b:
    <<: *default
    environment:
      WORKER_TYPE: b_setting
```

Notice that if you want nested elements - such as `environment` - to also have common values, you may need to do something like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  worker-a: &default
    image: alpine
    command: env
    environment: &environment
      COMMON_VAR_FOR_ALL: value
      WORKER_TYPE: a_setting
    # ... more definitions

  worker-b:
    <<: *default
    environment:
      <<: *environment
      WORKER_TYPE: b_setting
```

There is a good writeup on the subject [here](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/) and [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html#id2).

Comment: Well, this is actually amazing! Havent seen it before.